# PHP function not browsable

Tags: php

I'm trying to build an API with a JSON output, the second function is producing the desired output however I can't call it from the web. Whereas the first function returns as expected a large mass of text. Am I using something that is not compatible? I'm using version PHP 5.5.9 on an Ubuntu 14.04 server.

I can view the result of this function in both the terminal and the browser;

```
<?php
class ArticlesAPI {
        function top() {
                $db = new  mysqli("mysql-host.rds.amazonaws.com", "user", "password", "db_name");
                $results = $db->query("SELECT article_id, title, summary FROM top_articles");

        while ($row = $results->fetch_assoc()) {
            echo $row['article_id'];
            echo $row['title'];
            echo $row['summary'];
        }
        $results->close();
    }
}
$api = new ArticlesAPI;
$api->top();
?>
```

This function only returns a result in the terminal;

```
<?php
class ArticleAPI {
        function top() {
                $db = new  mysqli("mysql-host.rds.amazonaws.com", "user", "password", "db_name");
                $results = $db->query("SELECT article_id, title, summary  FROM top_articles");

                $articles = array();
                while($article = $results->fetch_assoc()){
                        $article_id = $article['article_id'];
                        $articles[$article_id][] = $article['title'];
                        $articles[$article_id][] = $article['summary'];

                }
                $results->close();
                $db->close();
                $json = json_encode($articles);
                echo $json;
        }
}
$api = new ArticleAPI;
$api->top();
?>
```

Comment: What sort of text is being output from the first block when run on the web? (Remember to remove any live data from the output before posting)

Comment: http://ec2-54-152-162-157.compute-1.amazonaws.com/mysql_test.php It's random data at the moment rather than live.

Comment: What the actual hell?

Comment: OH. Your code in the first case is echoing a ton of text without putting any spacing or separation between the values.

Comment: Also, in your second block, you should have `$articles[$article_id]['title'] = $article['title'];` and `$articles[$article_id]['summary'] = $article['summary'];`; you're trying to store the title and summary into the `i`th article in `$articles` without field names. My PHP is rusty, but I think that just dumps them into an unnamed array in the object.

Comment: Also, your MySQL connection strings are different between your two code samples. Not sure if that's important or just an artifact of copying the code onto SO.

Comment: When I did $articles[$article_id]['title'] = $article['title']; It overwrote each previous iteration and only stored the last value.

Comment: Weird. That shouldn't happen like that.

Comment: You could do `$articles[$article_id] = array('title' => $article['title'], 'summary' => $article['summary']);` instead of the two lines I provided earlier...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. There are 2 separate configuration files for CLI and for WEB check them and check server configuration(if http server parse php files etc.) you can do simple `<?php echo 'hello world';` and see if output is correct. If you open it via browser and you see anything more than hello world then PHP parser is not enabled.
2. Also when you output JSON you should set proper header for browser `application/json`
3. Check your output buffering settings. Maybe you use ob_* functions and don't flush output to browswer
4. Try putting `exit` after echo and check script after.
5. Set `error_reporting(E_ALL);` and `ini_set('display_errors', 1);` in first line of your app to check if there are errors.

Comment: http://ec2-54-152-162-157.compute-1.amazonaws.com/echo_test.php does this suggests PHP is set up correctly. I've added header('Content-Type: application/json'); before the json_encode and I've added exit; after echo. All to no avail, I will investigate your 3rd point now. Thanks

Comment: yes at least it is parsed by PHP parser. try now `<?php header('Content-type: application/json';  echo json_encode(array('test' => 'it works';));`

Comment: <?php
header('Content-type: application/json');
echo json_encode(array('test' => 'it works';));
?> (saved to echo_test.php, which produces no output)

Comment: http://ec2-54-152-162-157.compute-1.amazonaws.com/json_output.php Call to undefined function json_encode()... An apache2 restart fixed my problem.